# Unable to node specific values in firebase using swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My firebase database looks like this]

I am able to fetch all users but I want need user ID specific data.
For example you can see here are lots of users are registered but I need details only for 3 nodes:
 323QGP6qryTWs7EnnXRX1stgocP2

iy5ssz0ALphtgViALEOG0N4TeGd2

OlA0rhAVfsNvixe8KEsUmdCfuN42

Please help to get these records.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show the code that you tried ?

Comment: let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("7dqW2ckp8ZQQvQbJZRAGlRRZs8Z2").child("requests").queryOrdered(byChild: "OlA0rhAVfsNvixe8KEsUmdCfuN42").queryEqual(toValue: true)
        ref.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            
            
            print("Getting Requests:\(snapshot)")
            

        })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with : { snapshot in {
    if snapshot is NSNull{
        //handles errors
    }
    else{
       let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
           let firstDict = dict["323QGP6qryTWs7EnnXRX1stgocP2"] as? NSDictionary
           let secondDict = dict["iy5ssz0ALphtgViALEOG0N4TeGd2"] as? NSDictionary
           let thirdDict = dict["OlA0rhAVfsNvixe8KEsUmdCfuN42"] as? NSDictionary


           //Then to gather whichever node you want inside these users:
           let requestedNode = THEDICTIONARYYOUARELOOKINGAT["THE_NAME_OF_THE_NODE"] as? String //String, Int, Dictionary, array, boolean, ect.
       }
    }
})
```

Comment: This is not that I am looking for.
Nodes cannot be hardcoded because nodes will come randomly. Also I don't want to retrieve  all users because there are thousands of users.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you don’t know the key. And you don’t want to retrieve all users as least once. How do you want to get 3 specific user nodes?

Comment: Please look into this example

let ref1 = xyz/(uid)/requests
This path will some uid :
{
   uid1 = true
uid2 = true

}


and then,

let ref1 = xyz/(uid)/users
will return:
{
    uid1:{user details}
    uid2:{user details}

}

So,  I need users details of respective uid(s) from users list

Comment: Where do you find the requests? Under your uid? Or each uid has a request node?

Comment: each uid has a request node.
Thanks

Comment: I must say that - with your current design, the code above might be the only way. With that being said you could always add a Request nose outside of the UIDs and only look at that. Make sense?